# Visual Studio opaque compilation error indication

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to compile OpenCV with Cuda support using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 and get the following compilation error message:

```
22>  CMake Error at cuda_compile_generated_pyrlk.cu.obj.cmake:264 (message):
22>    Error generating file
22>    F:/Nir/dev/opencv/build/visualStudioA/modules/cudaoptflow/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/Debug/cuda_compile_generated_pyrlk.cu.obj
22>  
22>  
22>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(170,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.
```

Is there a way to get more information about the error? 
Increasing log verbosity, or getting the nvcc command that failed could be useful

Comment: did you try [verbose output from Cmake](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Is_there_an_option_to_produce_more_.27verbose.27_compiling.3F) ?

Comment: Mentioning the specific versions of OpenCV and Cuda probably wouldn't hurt...

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thank you, that was it.

Comment: @DanMašek I am using cuda v6.5 openCV v3.1

Answer (score 0):

Cuda compile verbosity can be enabled at CMakeCache.txt file:

```
//Print out the commands run while compiling the CUDA source file.
//  With the Makefile generator this defaults to VERBOSE variable
// specified on the command line, but can be forced on with this
// option.
CUDA_VERBOSE_BUILD:BOOL=ON
```

Comment: I could not enable Cuda verbosity flag using cmake-gui, you are invited to improve this answer if you find a way to do so.